# Assert statement in Selenium using C#

Tags: c#, selenium, assert

I am trying to make LoginFailTest, the idea is to give a successful result if the Login Fails and if it Logs in, it should give a Test Failed result.

The HTML code behind the page is:

```
<div id="waw1" class="grid" style="margin-top: 30px; padding-top: 20px;">
<div id="waw2" class="notice error">
<i class="icon-ok icon-large"/>
Please make sure the Organization ID, User ID, and Password you entered are  correct.
<a href="#close" class="icon-remove"/>
</div>
```

The C# code is:

```
 [TestClass]
public class LoginFailTest : ibankTest
{
[TestMethod]
public void User_Login_Fail()
{
Assert.IsTrue(LoginFail.Title, "Logged In");
}
}
```

My LoginFail class code is:

```
public class LoginFail
{
public static bool Title
{
get
{
var title = Driver.Instance.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='waw2']"));
if (title != null)
  return true;
return false;
 }
 }
```

The problem that I am facing is even if it Logs in, it is giving a successful test result, it should give me a Test Fails result here.

Can someone please help?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are handling the condition on the basis of element existence which is wrong because the element with the id always existing on the page, you need to check existence of text instead as below :

```
var title = Driver.Instance.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[contains(text(), 'Please make sure the Organization ID, User ID, and Password you entered are  correct.')]"));
if (title.Count > 0)
   return true;
return false;
```

**Note** : - `FindElements` always returns list of IWebElements if found otherwise returns empty list, It does not return `null` so you need to check its count to verify list is empty or not instead.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked the second time I ran the test :)

Comment: You could simplify this by using `return (title.Count > 0)` in place of the last three lines.

Answer (score 0):

What actually happening here is you are using:-

```
Assert.IsTrue(LoginFail.Title, "Logged In")
```

and your `LoginFail.Title` is expecting a boolean value either `true` or `false`, but in this case whether there would be a successful or failure for login, it will always have a `title` for the page. So the value `LoginFail.Title` is always returning `true`.

What you can actually do is get the `title` and make an exact comparison with the title that you are expecting.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, so can you recommend anything else other that IsTrue? i have used AreEqual(), but the thing is when the login fails, the test is not passing but it should be.

Comment: you can use `Assert.AreEqual("ExpectedTitleInCaseOfLoginFailure","ActualTitleInCaseOfLoginFailure")`. In this case whenever there would be a login failure, you would know the exact title and same you can compare.